# Safari lost half my extensions and passwords after a system crash

Tags: safari, password, crash, keychain, safari-extensions

[The crash was logged into console](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/KBVWG)
and it caused logout from my system.
After I've logged in again Safari lost most of my passwords and extensions.

I've already looked at [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7595760?start=0&tstart=0) and it didn't help.

I'm using iCloud Keychain and I've checked on my phone - the passwords are still there. I also looked into `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/` and all my extensions are still there, just not visible in safari preferences.

I've tried using Time Machine on `~/Library/Safari/` but it also didn't work.

I have to say that this is very annoying since it happened to me at least 3 times in past 2 years.

1) What can I do to restore all my iCloud passwords?

2) What can I do to restore all my Safari extensions without installing them again one-by-one?

3) What can I do to stop this from occurring again?

I guess 3) is too much to ask for, but I need at least a reliable procedure that can restore everything to the state it was before.
I'm also not the only person affected by this problem - my cousin turned to 1-Password exactly because of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have noticed from my question, I was very determined to find a solution and finally I found one. If you have a Time Machine setup then you're lucky. All you need to do is to restore those 4 folders (remember to select all the contents from the backup) to the time before the crash.

`~/Library/Safari/Extensions/`

`~/Library/Keychains`

`/Library/Keychains`

`/System/Library/Keychains`

(Probably not all are needed, but this worked for me)

Restart and open safari to check that everything is on place. Re-enable Keychain if it was disabled (mine was enabled, but turned to disabled in this process). Enjoy.